# The required version of Sharepoint foundation or sharepoint server is not installed on this system

Tags: 2013, web-part, visual-studio

[image]

I wanted to create a webpart using SharePoint solutions in visual studio 2015. I'm currently using sharepoint foundation 2013. I don't understand why I'm getting this error because it seems that I've already installed all the latest versions of software. Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: is visual studio and SharePoint install on same machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Visual Studio 2015 installation **must be** in your SharePoint server.

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint project templates that come with Visual Studio 2015 target SharePoint 2016.  That's why you're getting this error.  To build SharePoint farm solutions targeting SharePoint 2013, you need to use Visual Studio 2013.

Joe

Comment: This is not entirely true.  While you may very well be able to create a solution for SP 2016 on VS 2015, I can tell you for a fact that I have created many, many solutions targeting SP 2013 (web parts, list definitions, event receivers, you name it) using VS 2015.

Comment: It's true that it isn't entirely correct, it really depends on the version of office dev tools you have installed.  VS 2013 comes with the version of office dev tools that targets SharePoint 2013.  Now that you mention it, I believe 2015 didn't come with any version of office dev tools, since SP 2016 wasn't out yet, it's a separate download.  VS 2017 comes with the version of office dev tools for SharePoint 2016. So I guess he really just needs to uninstall office dev tools and get the appropriate version for SP 2013. Or use VS 2013.