# SharePoint Server 2019 On Hyper V - The required version of SharePoint Foundation or SharePoint Server is not installed on this system

Tags: sharepoint-server, visual-studio, 2019

[image]

Hello Experts,

I had installed SharePoint 2019 and Visual Studio 2019 in Hyper V. When i try to create an Empty project in Visual Studio Getting this error, Please help.

Please find the below screenshots for more information.

[image]

[image]

Once i click on create it is showing the error.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: have you checked the old question here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/234943/the-required-version-of-sharepoint-foundation-or-sharepoint-server-is-not-instal

Comment: This old question is related to VS 2015, And more over the answer suggesting to install both on same server. But i had already installed both on the same server.

Comment: are you able to open the sharepoint page within the same server with browser? Sometimes the url is not resolved properly

Comment: Yes i am able to access SharePoint through the browser with in the server, Just to mention this environment setup done in Hyper V

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have selected the SharePoint 2019 Project templates in visual studio.

If there is no valid template, try to reinstall Office Development tools like this:

1. Run VS2019 > Tools > Get tools and features
2. Uncheck Office/Sharepoint development and click Modify
3. Wait when installation will be completed. After that install them
   using the same method

More information for your reference:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44394189/sharepoint-is-not-installed

[SharePoint 2019 Project templates in Visual Studio 2019](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/272040/sharepoint-2019-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2019)

Comment: I can see the SharePoint templates in VS2019. When I try to create SharePoint project with SharePoint 2019 empty project I get this error. SharePoint 2019 and VS2019 are both installed on same Hyper-V windows server.

Comment: Please provide more information about the SharePoint project template in visual studio such as screenshoot.

Comment: Please find the screenshots i updated the question.

Comment: From your screenshoot, it is normal. We suggest you run visual studio as administrator, if the issue still exists, you may need to re-install visual studio.

Comment: I had already run visual studio several times as Administrator but still i go the same error. I will give a try to to re-install VS2019.

Comment: Waiting for your feedback.